# What sentence adverb to use to introduce a sentence expressing the reason for something?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, reason-why

I am trying to 'conjure up' a chart on result, reason, purpose, and contrast for my students, and I am really hard put to come up with a satisfying adverb to introduce the sentence mentioning the reason for something.

> Result: *I work hard. Therefore, I am successful.* (adverb introducing the sentence mentioning the result)
>
> Reason: *I am successful. Naturally, I work hard.* (adverb introducing the sentence mentioning the reason)

Is there an adverb other than 'Naturally' for reason, as obvious as 'As a result/Consequently/Therefore' for result?

I have thought of 'Obviously', 'Evidently', 'Of course', but they are hardly more satsifying than 'Naturally', are they?

Comment: "Therefore" in the context you use it seems quite odd to me. A more usual way to phrase the sentence would be "I work hard, that's why I am successful", which relates to the reason and not to the result.

Comment: Understandably, hence, and logically are three that come to mind.

Comment: Is your idea to express the notion that nothing other than hard work could explain the resulting success?

Comment: @WalterMitty: yes, exactly.

Comment: You can use “because”.

Comment: ... or _as a consequence/result of [my] [hard work / working hard]_. 'As a result of' is a fixed expression.

Comment: 'Therefore' itself also works here. 'I am successful. Therefore, I work hard.' meaning in this case 'I am successful. Therefore, it must be that I work hard.'

Comment: *Unsurprisingly*, *predictably*, or if you're really desperate *[explanatorily](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explanatorily)*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your second sentence is missing a link to the first. We are left guessing as to the relationship between the two.

*Therefore* establishes that the sentence before is the reason for what is stated in the following. A similar adverb expressing the opposite relationship, that the sentence previous is the result of the reason given in the one following is what's needed, but *naturally*, *perforce*, etc. do not do so explicitly. We are left guessing whether being successful has caused the speaker to work hard or working hard has caused him to be successful. The sentences may not have a cause and effect relationship at all depending on the context.

This would produce the result desired:

And, to be so, I work hard.

I don't believe a single adverb with the meaning of *to be so* exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the conjunction ***for,*** [defined by MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for) as "because." In this case:

> I am successful. **For** I work hard.

There are certain prescriptive types who will tell you not to start a sentence with a conjunction, but this usage is so well-established that you can safely ignore them.